Edit links to a new month's file
I have a checks file that brings in data from several other files to perform various checks. Every month, I copy last month's check file, copy it into a new folder, and edit links to the new month.

Each month's check file will be in the same folder as that month's other files.
The new month's check file will be in a different folder from last month's.
The other files will have a name along the lines of "This Report v1.21 - NYC", "This Report v1.21 - Boston", etc.
The following month, the naming will be the same, except it will be v1.22 or something.
So, each month's folder will have three types of files: the main file, the city files created from the main file, and the checking file. Each month, I copy the main file and the checking file from the previous month's folder and paste them into this month's folder. I then run vba in the main file to create the city files for the month. I then want to open the checking file and update the links from last month's city files to this month's city files. All current month's files will be open and no prior month's files will be open. The links to be updated are in-cell formulas. The type that are edited by navigating to Data > Edit Links

Could I find last month's links by using "*NYC*" and replace with this month's NYC file? Or something along those lines?
There are 10ish links in the file and none will have a duplicate city name, but they all have the same name up to their city suffix.
In short, I think what I would like to do is replace the "*... - NY" link with something like ThisWorkbook.Path & "* - NY"

You can use Workbook.ChangeLink method (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.changelink) to update a link, and you can loop over Workbook.LinkSources(xlExcelLinks) to find all of the links which need to be changed. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.linksources

Please share the details of the code you tried and describe the issue you are encountering.
How do I ask a good question?

Might be useful to add your code for "I then run vba in the main file to create the city files for the month" and some one might help you fold in the code for changing the links into that code.

@taller I haven't tried much because I have no idea how to do so. The macro provides the following code, though:
ActiveWorkbook.ChangeLink Name:= _
"G:\Path\Last Month's File - NY.xlsm" _
, NewName:= _
"G:\Path\This Month's File - AMITA.xlsm" _
, Type:=xlExcelLinks

@tim adding that code is not feasible. Also, in that code, I do not reference the checking file at all. The checking file is only opened/updated after all other files are complete.

Generally here it's a good idea to have some code in your post, or you risk having it closed before you get an answer.  It's much easier to suggest small additions to existing code than to have to guess how you're already working in VBA.

@tim the only code I have for this is what is already in that comment above:
ActiveWorkbook.ChangeLink Name:= _ "G:\Path\Last Month's File - NY.xlsm" _ , NewName:= _ "G:\Path\This Month's File - AMITA.xlsm" _ , Type:=xlExcelLinks
That's the part I'm trying to edit based on the file names I have

You can have the checking file open while you create the new files, and as each one is created loop over the existing checking file links and find the one which contains the city name: that's the easiest point at which to change the links, and why I suggested you post the code which creates the new files to be linked to.

Oh interesting. I figured it would be easier to just change it like I have in that code above and just do them all at once when I open the checking file.

Thank you for the responses. I took a different approach that worked for me. I used a formula in the checking file to get the old file paths which allowed me to do the following:
Dim OldNYCLink As String
Dim NewNYCLink As String
OldNYCLink = Range("E51")
NewNYCLink = Left(ThisWorkbook.FullName, Len(ThisWorkbook.FullName) - 5) & " - NYC.xlsm"

Dim OldBostonLink As String
Dim NewBostonLink As String
OldBostonLink = Range("F51")
NewBostonLink = Left(ThisWorkbook.FullName, Len(ThisWorkbook.FullName) - 5) & " - Boston.xlsm"


Based on the poor information that you provide I believe this might help you:
Sub ReplaceLink()
    Dim oldLink As String
    Dim newLink As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim cell As Range
        
    ' Define the date in a cell
    Set NewDate = Range("A2")     'Make sere that cell A2 has the proper date  
          
    ' Define the old link and the new link
    oldLink = "*... - NY"
    newLink = ThisWorkbook.Path & NewDate & "\* - NY"

    ' Loop through each worksheet
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        ' Loop through each cell in the worksheet
        For Each cell In ws.UsedRange
            ' Check if the cell contains the old link
            If InStr(cell.Value, oldLink) > 0 Then
                ' Replace the old link with the new link
                cell.Value = Replace(cell.Value, oldLink, newLink)
            End If
        Next cell
    Next ws

    MsgBox "Links replaced successfully!"

End Sub

